# Can using pointer to pointer solve non updation of class member as explained here? If yes how?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a C++ class "**Node**" which is supposed to manage a **DiGraph** of **NODES** and **EDGES**.

```
class Node{
string data;
vector<string> links;
map<string, Node> children;
Node* parent;
unsigned int nol;
}
```

- **data** is node id or name
- **links** is the container of node names of nodes having edge from this node to them
- **children** is a map of nodes. map like map[linkName, Node]
- **parent** is the parent node, for root it is 0
- **nol** is no of children.

I feel this is not a good way to implement this? Moving forward, i have a **setLinkTo()** function, and a constructor as shown below.

```
Node(Node* p, string name){
    parent = &(*p);
    data = name;
    nol=0;
    (*parent).setLinkTo(this);
}
```

in the first line, I try to send a pointer to parent. So that I can use it in the future. I don't want to send copies of this. then the last line I add the node to the **NODE's Parent**.

```
void setLinkTo(Node* n){
    (*n).parent = this;
    nol++;
    string link = (*n).data;
    map<string, Node>::iterator it;
    it = children.find(link);

    if(it != children.begin() && it != children.end()){
        (*it).second.setLinkTo(n);
    }
    else{
        links.insert(links.end(), link);
        children.insert(children.end(), pair<string, Node> (link, (*n)));
    }
}
```

I get really confused with **this** pointer.
Well everything is working as expected. But the problem occurs when:

```
main(){
Node root;
Node foo(&root, "foo");
Node bar(&root, "bar");
Node zo(&foo, "zo");
root.displayGraph();
}
```

FIRSTLY, IT NEVER DISPLAYS zo.
SECONDLY, foo.displayGraph() displays zo.

obviously, you must be wondering about the displayGraph() function.

```
void displayGraph(){
    cout<<data<<endl<<"\t";
    for(map<string, Node>::iterator it=children.begin();it!= children.end(); ++it){
        it->second.displayGraph();
    }   

}
```

if I add line to Main() before **root.displayGragh()**

```
root.setLinkTo(&foo);
```

then, the map has two **foo**, even though it said on C++  DOCS that maps keys have to be unique(Which I don't understand). and zo is displayed at the second **foo**'s child.
**How can I update *root* and *foo* when *zo* itself is created?**

And, mainly, I have been working on this for 4 days now, and if my approach is wrong, which involved trial and error of everything from Linked lists etc, but failed miserably as I was unable to reference edges properly, tell me.

So, here is the pastebin, http://pastebin.com/RTWQx18i, if am doing it wrong, please tell me. I have to complete this assignment, and I just need help taking the first few steps to solving the first question here **(the same about digraph and nodes)** http://www.smu.edu/Guildhall/Admissions/PortfolioRequirements/Programming

If at all am doing it right, then an ideas to complete that sortChildren() function to sort the repeated children all over the digraph and merge the set of children to their respective parents.

Comment: `(*n).parent` is normally written `n->parent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in: `map<string, Node>` the map during adding new elements may involve copies of Node ( new map is created for this local object and everything starts to be desynchronized ).

I have created working version with some modifications.
The most important change is keeping in map pointers instead of objects, but you must be careful with dealocations and lifecycle of added objects.

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
    string data;
    vector<string> links;
    map<string, Node*> children;
    Node* parent;
    unsigned int nol;

    Node(Node* p, string name)
    {
        parent = p;
        data = name;
        nol = 0;
        parent->setLinkTo(this);
    }

    Node()
        :parent(nullptr)
    {}

    void displayGraph()
    {
        cout << data << endl << "\t";
        for (map<string, Node*>::iterator it = children.begin(); it != children.end(); ++it){
            it->second->displayGraph();
        }
    }
private:
    void setLinkTo(Node* n)
    {
        nol++;
        const string& link = n->data;
        map<string, Node*>::iterator it = children.find(link);

        if (it != children.begin() && it != children.end()){
            it->second->setLinkTo(n);
        }
        else{
            links.insert(links.end(), link);
            children.insert(children.end(), make_pair(link, n));
        }
    }
};

main(){
    Node root;
    Node foo(&root, "foo");
    Node bar(&root, "bar");
    Node zo(&foo, "zo");
    root.displayGraph();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! what is `:parent` what is `:` here. and what is that constructor?

Comment: `:parent(nullptr)` is parent variable initialization. The equivalent code is: `Node(){ parent = nullptr; }`

Comment: Consider vote up or accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: oh ok, I had constuctor like this `Node(){ parent = 0;data = "/";nol = 0;}`

Comment: cant vote up or anything I tried. needs reputation!! :(

Comment: You can use your constructor. It's also proper. I had to create my own to show the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

The data member `children` is a `map<string, Node>`.
This means that when an element is inserted in the map like you do here:

```
void setLinkTo(Node* n){
    // ... snip
    if(it != children.begin() && it != children.end()){
     }
    else{
        children.insert(children.end(), pair<string, Node> (link, (*n)));
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
    }
}
```

You insert a *copy* of node `*n`. This in turn means that any subsequent modifications to this child are done in the *copy* of the `Node`, not in the `Node` object you meant to link to.

Probably it is as simple as changing your `children` to `map<string, Node*>` and update the `insert` accordingly.

Comment: But what happens to removal? removal of child. Plus I heard you should not have containers of pointers? or is that having containers of pointers, I have to free memory by myself?
So if i have a `vector<Node *> links` then `Node *p = links[i]; free(p);` wil work?

Comment: Delete the entry from the `map`. Do not `delete` the pointer - you seem to be doing the memory management outside the `Node` class.

Answer (score 0):

In your children map, your value is Node which is stored by copy, and all further changes to the original object are lost. You need to store pointers to Node there, `map<string, Node*>`.